# If a measure $\mu$ is less than a measure $\nu$ on a generating $\pi$-system, can we conclude that $\mu \leq \nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$, $\nu$ be finite measures on the non-degenerate compact interval $[a, b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ provided with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. It is well-known that if $\mu(B) = \nu(B)$ for every Borel set $B$ belonging to a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{B}([a, b])$ and that includes $[a, b]$, then $\mu = \nu$. Is the same true if the equality is replaced by an inequality? In other words, suppose $\mu(B) \leq \nu(B)$ for every Borel set $B$ belonging to a $\pi$-system that generates $\mathcal{B}([a, b])$ and that includes $[a, b]$. Is it the case that $\mu \leq \nu$?

Comment: you may be interested in this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177317/simple-inequality-for-measures

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks. It's interesting that the answer to your question is positive, whereas the answer to mine is negative. The two questions seem almost identical, on the surface. Evidently the product space structure changes the situation significantly.

Comment: added an answer with explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the following $\pi$ system:
$$\mathcal{C}=\{[a,t), [a,b]\; \vert \;t \in [a,b]\}$$

define

$\mu([a,t) = t-a + 100$

$\nu ([a,t)) = t-a + 50$

$\mu([a,b]) = 100 + (b - a) $

$\nu ([a,b]) = 100 +(b-a)$.

Note that  $\mu(C) \geq \nu(C) $ for every $C \in \mathcal{C}$, but $\mu (\{b\}) = \mu ([a,b]) - \lim_n \mu([a,b-1/n) = 0$ and $\nu (\{b\}) = 50$.

This is possible because we can't assure that $B \backslash A \in \mathcal{C}$ for a $\pi$- system

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate a bit. First of all, the above example of Conrado works perfectly, but perhaps the following one is a bit easier to memorize, and it may clearly deliver the main idea that Conrado formulated in the last message of his answer.

Let $\Omega = \{a,b\}$ and $\mathcal C = (\{a\}, \Omega)$, then $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system that generates $2^\Omega$. Define $\mu = (1,0)$ and $\nu = (0,1)$. Obviously, $\mu \geq \nu$ on $\mathcal C$, but it's not true that $\mu\geq \nu$ on $2^\Omega$.

Notice though that a [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177317/5887) result holds true. The difference is that the rectangles do not only form a $\pi$-system, they also have an important property that any element of the algebra that they generate can be written as a union of rectangles - hence $\mu\geq \nu$ on the whole algebra which is in turn enough for the inequality to hold over the $\sigma$-algebra. Clearly, in counterexample above (as in Conrado's) the algebra can't be written as a union of elements of the $\pi$-system, hence the inequality does not have to hold on the algebra. So
$$
  \mu \geq_{\mathcal C} \nu \quad \overset{?}{\implies} \quad  \mu \geq_{\mathcal A}\nu \quad \iff\quad \mu \geq_{\mathcal F} \nu \quad \implies \quad \mu \geq_{\mathcal C} \nu
$$
where $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system that generates an algebra $\mathcal A$, which generates a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. Of course, the middle equivalence is trivial in finite space since $\mathcal A = \mathcal F$, and the challenge of my question was to show it holds for the general case.

Comment: Thanks. This is illuminating. However, your example doesn't quite match the specification given in my question, for two reasons: (1) I stipulated that $\Omega$ be a compact interval, (2) I stipulated that $\Omega$ should be a member of the $\pi$-system.

Comment: @EvanAad: edited. The first condition does not seem to be relevant here at all, it's purely measure theoretical question, you can add to my $\Omega$ the interior without changing anything. The second condition might have been important, but apparently no: a simple edit of my original example took care of that.

Comment: What does $\mu = (1,0)$ and $\nu = (0,1)$ mean?

Comment: @echinodermata: since set of measure on $n$ points is exactly $\Bbb R^n$, I just use this notation to say that $\mu(a)=1$, $\mu(b)=0$, and similarly $\nu(a)=0$, $\nu(b)=1$